# ZX calculus: What do diamond and loop mean?

Tags: zx-calculus

Recently, I started to study practical application of ZX calculus but I am confused by meaning of "diamond" and "loop".

---

**Issue no. 1:**
There are these rules:

*B-rule*

[image: b-rule]

and *D-rule*

[image: d-rule]

But this example seems to use the rules wrongly:

[image: Example 1]

In the middle of a digram, B-rule is used, however, I do not see any loop or diamonds justifying this step (i.e. a disconection of nodes).

Similar situation occurs in this example:

[image: Example 2]

**Why is it possible to ignore loop and diamonds?**

---

**Issue no. 2:**

Interpreation of a diamond in Hilbert space is this:

> Diamond = $\sqrt{2}$

What does mean that diamond is $\sqrt{2}$? **Is it a normalization constant?**

Interpreation of a loop in Hilbert space is this:

> Loop represent the dimension of underlying Hilbert space

Assuming D-rule, loop should represent two diamonds hence $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} = 2$ which is dimension of Hilbert space for description of single qubit states. But ZX calculus can be used for any number of qubits. **What does it mean that loop represent a dimension? How is a dimension of "multi-qubits" Hilbert space represented?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you agree to treat diagrams up to a constant factor, then you can ignore loops and diamonds. As you correctly guessed, it's a normalization constant.
2. For a multi-qubit system, you represent an identity operator with several wires. If you trace them, you get dimension equal to $2^n$, and in the diagram you represent this dimension as $n$ disjoint loops each contributing a factor of 2.